# Remove Permissions from android manifest xml file with powershell script

Tags: xml, powershell, android-manifest

I have a manifest file containing following content.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.dlginventory.dev"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0">

    <!-- explicity remove -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" tools:node="remove" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/> <!-- Approximate location - If you want to use promptLocation for letting OneSignal know the user location. -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/> <!--  Precise location If you want to use promptLocation for letting OneSignal know the user location. -->



</manifest>
```

I want to remove last two permission through powershell but unable to do this.
I am able to get required permission but not able to remove.
Here is the script I used to get content.

```
$androidManifextFile = "C:\Users\BilalAbbasi\Desktop\Temp\AndroidManifest.xml"
        $newPackageName = "com.dlginventory"

        $xml = [Xml](Get-Content $androidManifextFile) #this loads the config as XML
        $rootElements = $xml.get_DocumentElement(); #this gets all root elements only

        ##$permissionElements = $rootElements.'uses-permission'
        ##$element1 = $permissionElements.name -eq "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        $element1 = $rootElements.'uses-permission'.name -eq "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"
        $element2 = $rootElements.'uses-permission'.name -eq "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"

        $rootElements.package = $newPackageName #update the package name
        $xml.Save($androidManifextFile); #save the file in xml format
```

I have test with Remove child and remove all function but not able to do so.

Comment: Any one there to help?

Comment: Use `-replace` after getting the element?

Answer (score 2):

You could do like this:

```
$androidManifextFile = "C:\Users\BilalAbbasi\Desktop\Temp\AndroidManifest.xml"
$newPackageName = "com.dlginventory"

$xml = [Xml](Get-Content $androidManifextFile) #this loads the config as XML

# Define a list of nodes to remove
$nodesToRemove = "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION", "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"

# Select all "uses-permission" nodes
# Match them against the list of nodes to remove
# Remove each match from the document
$xml.manifest.SelectNodes("uses-permission") | Where-Object { $_.name -in $nodesToRemove } | ForEach-Object { $xml.Manifest.RemoveChild($_) }

$xml.manifest.package = $newPackageName #update the package name

$xml.Save($androidManifextFile); #save the file in xml format
```

Answer (score 1):

There might be a better solution using an `[xml]` base type method, but this works:

```
$File = (Get-Content $androidManifextFile)
$File -replace "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION", "" | Set-Content $androidManifextFile
```

To remove the whole line or a different section, modify the -replace argument.

Answer (score 0):

Here is result I got

```
(Get-Content $androidManifextFile) | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" } | Set-Content $androidManifextFile
(Get-Content $androidManifextFile) | Where-Object { $_ -notmatch "android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" } | Set-Content $androidManifextFile
```